# How to find the smallest closest number in a list in python

Tags: python, list, numbers

I want to know how can I find the smallest closest number in a list to a given number. 
For example:

```
number = 20

list_of_numbers = [4, 9, 15, 25]
```

I tried this:

```
min(list_of_numbers, key=lambda x:abs(x-number))
```

The output is 25 and not 15. The problem is that it always gives me the "biggest closest" and not the "smallest closest".

Comment: Ummm I tested your method It gave me 15 in Python 3.5.2 and 2.7

Comment: 2.7 gives me 15 too

Comment: Oh, perhaps mine is too old. All right thanks guys, I have tested it with a more recent one and it works.

Comment: @KazeRyuga: What Python version are you using?

Comment: @Blender it was Python 2.1.1

Comment: @KazeRyuga: It's more than 15 years old...

Comment: 2.1.1? Are you a time-traveller from 2000?

Comment: Yeah pretty old. I was working on an old project, it was using Python 2.1

Comment: @KazeRyuga If it is really 2.1.1 then I am not sure how the accepted answer is going to help you -- Neither `key` existed in Python 2.1.1 nor `sorted()`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I'm going to rewrite my entire project with Python 3.5 , so his answer is right

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could make the `key` also contain the number itself and use that for breaking ties:

```
min(list_of_numbers, key=lambda x: (abs(x - number), x))
```

Your behavior is strange, though. It might be a bug. You might be able to work around it by using `sorted`, which is stable:

```
sorted(list_of_numbers, key=lambda x: abs(x - number))[0]
```

Comment: is order dependent, testing the original with [4,9,25,15] I get 25 while the [4,9,15,25] give 15, therefore it return the first one that is found in python 3.5 and 2.7, and maybe in python 2.1 is the last one that it returned

Comment: @Copperfield, [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#min) (>=3.2) guarantees that the first item is returned, [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) doesn't.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu It is just a documentation issue with Python 2.7.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, just a documentation issue?! Where's the bug report? :-) If it's not in documentation, it does not exist. Because of programmers abusing undocumented behavior people have a hard time trying to make old programs run on new systems. Microsoft has probably wasted a lot of resources trying to preserve compatibility with old software.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Not of all of the changes made to Python 3 are applied to Python 2.7 anymore. Unlike Microsoft there's nothing closed source here, you can always check the source to be sure. :-) Related issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue9802

Answer (score 6):

Add the number from the list of numbers to the key, so it's taken into account.

```
min(list_of_numbers, key=lambda x: (abs(x - number), x))
```

Also if you want the *first* number from the list which matches the requirement, add the index to the key:

```
min(enumerate(list_of_numbers), key=lambda ix: (abs(ix[1] - number), ix[0]))[1]
```

Though this would only be needed under [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min), because [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min) guarantees that:

> If multiple items are minimal, the function returns the first one encountered.   This is consistent with other sort-stability preserving tools such as `sorted(iterable, key=keyfunc)[0]` and `heapq.nsmallest(1, iterable, key=keyfunc)`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
min(list_of_numbers, key=lambda x:abs(x-number))
```

Try  this :

```
number = 20
list_of_numbers = [4, 9, 15, 25]
list_of_numbers.sort(reverse=True)
min(list_of_numbers,key=lambda x : x - number > 0 )
```