# A python expression using min(list_1, key = func) that returns the largest number in a list smaller than a given number

Tags: python, list, min

The recommended expression that was given as an answer to question:
[How to find the smallest closest number in a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271548/how-to-find-the-smallest-closest-number-in-a-list-in-python) was what I was searching for.
However when I tried to run it something happened that I wasn't expecting.

I used the list and the number from the question above, i.e.:

`list_of_numbers = [4, 9, 15, 25]`

`number = 20`

and the expression:

`min(list_of_numbers, key=lambda x: (abs(x - number), x))`

As expected, I got the number 15.

However, when I changed the number to:

```
number = 91
```

`list_new = []
 for i in range(4,98,4):
      list_new.append(i)`

```
min(list_of_numbers, key=lambda x: (abs(x - number), x))
```

list_new is:

```
[4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48, 52, 56, 60, 64, 68, 72, 76, 80, 84, 88, 92, 96]
```

So I expected an answer of 88, since that corresponds with what happened when I tried the original question, however, I keep getting 92.

If I looked at the wrong question and answer to start with, I would appreciate a reference to the answer my question seeks.

I am running this on Python 3.6.

Comment: 91 is closer to 92 than 88. It finds the arithmetically closest number so I'm not sure how you interpret your initial result as corresponding to the second one. Same thing happened in both cases. The expression does return the first number in the list if there are multiple equally close ones. But that's not what happens in your second example.

Comment: If that's the case I may have looked at the wrong answer. Do you have a suggestion as to how to retrieve the largest number in a list smaller than a given number? That's the question I was originally looking for an answer to, preferably using min().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code finds the *closest* number, since it uses the absolute value.

You might consider to just use a list comprehension intstead:

```
>>> L = range(4,98,4)
>>> number = 91
>>> max([n for n in L if n < number])
88
```

Comment: you can get rid of the inner list comp and just use a gen exp

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your key function asymmetric, e.g. by using a if-condition:

```
max(list_of_numbers, key=lambda x:x if x < number else -1e99)
```